# How to Configure Zimbra-8.8 mail server in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dns, zimbra

We need to configure Zimbra mail server version 8.8 (Latest Version) in Ubuntu 14.04.

Kindly provide any documentation or any url.

Answer (score 1):

The original documentation for [Zimbra](https://zimbra.org/documentation/zimbra-collaboration/8.8) is good and 
complete.